# Selenium Webdriver: Element is not currently visible on running through Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

Basically I want to click the on a element that became available after clicking on another  element:

```
WebElement element;
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='btn-expand btn-exp-right hide-text']"));
element.click();

// Below is the explict wait that will wait max 45 seconds for below element. And this element will be only be available after clicking above one.


action.explictWait(45, By.xpath("//span[@class='btn-plus']"));
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='btn-plus']]"));

// Error this encounter on clicking.
element.click();
```

While running through Jenkins I am unable to click `"//span[@class='btn-plus']]"`. However this is working fine while running locally.

Please reply soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the jenkin server and launch the page and see if the button is visible.